# Move data from Excel to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, excel, postgresql, automation, xlrd

I would like to write and automate a Python script to read data from an Excel spreadsheet and insert data into a PostgreSQL database table.

I realize that this is the exact opposite of what most people try to do. Everyone seems to be going from Postgres to csv. But I kind of need to do this because of the way we collect certain data elements at my company.

I was hoping someone had pointers. I've played around with xlrd and pscopg2 but I'm fairly new to programming and could use a little nudge.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two pieces. Once to interact w/ Excel (something like http://www.python-excel.org/), and one to interface w/ Postgres (http://initd.org/psycopg/).

Comment: I have no clue.
PS: I'm using xlrd and psycopg2. I'll be back if it doesn't work out. Thanks!